# Appium Camera Functionality not working

Tags: appium

I m checking the skype app functionality and trying to change the profile pic of it. I tried two queries. But android device is not capturing the image.

I tried the two queries:

```
driver.sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA);

d.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_CAMERA);
```

Comment: did you try my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

To Automate Camera we can use Android [KeyCodes](http://testingalert.com/automate-android-actions-using-appium/).

Scenario:-

Launch the app
Login into the app
Go to Profile
Change the Profile image using Camera

```
public static void keyBoardEvent(int eventNumber)

{

try

{

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C adb shell input keyevent " + eventNumber);

Thread.sleep(3000);

}

catch (Throwable t)

{

t.printStackTrace();

}

}
```

By passing the eventNumber , we are able to perform desired event.

For Camera Click, Event Number is 27.

Camera Click implementation:-

```
public void clickCamera()

{

Keywords.keyBoardEvent(27);

System.out.print("Clicked on Camera ");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

driver.sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA); and Keywords.keyBoardEvent(27);